# add package to WinPE using DISM failes

Tags: windows, windows-pe

I'm having trouble with adding a package to a custom WinPe file.

I try to add a package  (using: `dism /image:c:\temp\mount /Add-Package /PackagePath:"C:\Program Files\Windows AIK\Tools\PETools\x86\WinPE_FPs\winpe_scripting.cab"` in a command prompt with administrative privileges) I get this message:

> An error occurred trying to open - C:\Program Files\Windows AIK\Tools\PETools\x86\WinPE_FPs\winpe_scripting.cab Error: 0x80070003
>   An error occurred trying to open - C:\Program Files\Windows AIK\Tools\PETools\x86\WinPE_FPs\winpe_scripting.cab Error: 0x80070003
>
> Error: 3
>
> An error occurred trying to open - C:\Program Files\Windows AIK\Tools\PETools\x86\WinPE_FPs\winpe_scripting.cab Error: 0x80070003

When I look in the *dism.log* I see this:

> Incorrect parameter C:\Program Files\Windows
>   AIK\Tools\PETools\x86\WinPE_FPs\winpe_scripting.cab - path not found -

However, I checked the path and there is no error in it.
Also in the *dism.log* there is this error:

> DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=3564 TID=4204 Failed to get the underlying CBS package. - CDISMPackageManager::OpenPackageByPath(hr:0x80070003)

I have no clue of what that is.

Can somebody help me with adding packages to a WinPe custom wim image?

Thanks in advance.

Jack

Answer (score 0):

try copy the CAB to your C:\temp folder. And try to import it again in your mounted image at C:\temp\mount.